# Is there any reason to translate coordinates?

Tags: traducción

The English "Treasure Island" contains this:

> In a few cases, to be sure, the name of a place would be added,
>   as "Offe Caraccas," or a mere entry of latitude and longitude, as "62o
>   17' 20", 19o 2' 40"."

The Spanish translation is:

> En algunos lugares, para mayor seguridad, se añadía el nombre de algún lugar como "Á la altura de Caracas," ó bien una mera cita geográfica de latitud y
>       longitud como, 53° 17' 20" y 19° 2' 40".

Why in tarnation would '62o 17' 20"' become '53° 17' 20"'?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Longitude was set using a multitude of prime meridians before the international adoption of the Greenwich meridian, which Spain adopted in 1901 after a century and a half using the Cádiz meridian (according to [this Spanish source](http://fabian.balearweb.net/post/76746)). I suppose the translator took that point as a longitude and attempted to set it to another meridian (if he wanted to set it to the Cádiz meridian he failed, as it was [6 degrees west of Greenwich](https://books.google.com/books?id=YhoPAQAAMAAJ&pg=PR15&lpg=PR15&dq=cadiz%20meridian&source=bl&ots=T8hN0s_EnC&sig=FHxDipZABuhmYhTAhAuwHYLAKEY&hl=en&sa=X&ei=OPFpVZTlKsyhNu_zgKAK&ved=0CEMQ6AEwCTgU#v=onepage&q=cadiz%20meridian&f=false)). Other than that, it could have been a writing or typesetting error, a badly-printed English copy with unclear characters in that particular passage, or a conjunction of all those factors.